# How to Make All External Links Open Up in a Custom Sized Popup Window?

Tags: javascript

Using this code, I am able to select all external links and make it so they open in a new tab:

```
$.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
    return !obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/)
           && (obj.hostname != location.hostname)
           && !obj.href.match(/^javascript\:/)
           && !obj.href.match(/^$/)
};

$('a:external').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Is there a way that I can modify that

so it does this function:

```
 var newwindow; function poptastic(url){
  newwindow=window.open(url,'name', 'height=800,width=1020,scrollbars=yes');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}}
```

Ultimately I want it to just do the bottom function, but to all external links instead of having to go in and add this to each external link:

```
 <a href="javascript:poptastic('http://www.external-link.com')">External Link</a>
```

(I know that some people don't like this, requiring the user to have a new window popped open instead of just doing target="_blank", but I have asked a small group of users in the age group for my client's site, and they all preferred this method greatly over it opening in a new tab).

Also, is there a way that I can add to the top part so any .PDF files will also do the above command?  Its set up so its only for external sites, but could you make an exception for any .pdf too?

Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a:external').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    poptastic(this.href);
});
```

That is, on click of any of the external links prevent the default click behaviour (which would of course be to navigate to the specified url, replacing the current page), and instead call your `poptastic()` function passing the href.

(You could just put the body of your `poptastic` directly into the `.click` handler...)

**EDIT:** To do the same for PDF, if your intention is to modify the `:external` selector to include PDFs - where I'm defining "PDF" as being an href ending in `".pdf"` - you could do this:

```
$.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
    return !obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/)
           && (obj.hostname != location.hostname || /.pdf$/.test(obj.href))
           && !obj.href.match(/^javascript\:/)
           && !obj.href.match(/^$/)
};
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/RevXG/4/

Comment: Hmm.. I tried that, but now the link doesn't do anything upon clicking?  Is that due to the way that i have poptastic set up? and also, could there be a negative effect to preventing the default click behavior as some platforms like apple computers disregard this function and just open up in a new tab doing the same thing that target="_blank" does, would the link not even work on platforms that do that? or is target="_blank" essentially preventing the default click behavior too?

Comment: EDIT: Also, switching out what you said breaks the function of external links and no longer allows the function to work.

Comment: OK, I copied the code directly out of my answer and the `poptastic` function from your question and pasted into [this jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RevXG/1/) and it works fine. Regarding your questions about Apple computers, why do you think they disregard `preventDefault()`?

Comment: It is?  What browser are you using because it's not working for me? I tried clearing my cache, using firefox?  It's just opening it up in the same window/doing nothing for me?

Comment: My apologies, answer and demo updated. http://jsfiddle.net/RevXG/4/ _Now_ it works. I had the regex `.test()` method syntax backwards. (I don't know why the previous demo worked for me at first, because it doesn't work now, but the _new_ demo works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox.)

Comment: Oh wow! How stupid, I copied the code directly, but I kept getting a token error "ILLEGAL" and I noticed that in my JS it showed "â€‹" next to the ending } tag, and that's what was doing it, it was working in your fiddle but not on my site.  Thanks so much for everything, it seems to work perfectly, I am going try replacing all of my links and see if it works fine.  Could you see any unforseen issues doing it this way though?  Should I set up some type of backup system?  or do you think it'll be fine?  Thanks again!

Comment: I would expect it to work unless the user has a _really_ aggressive popup blocker installed. `window.open()` called from a click handler is OK for "normal" popup blockers. If a user happens to have JS disabled in their browser that's not a problem because your click handler (obviously) won't run and the links will just behave as normal - which incidentally is a good reason not to do `href="javascript:poptastic(...)"` as mentioned in your question.

Comment: Okay very interesting, well as a backup-backup, is there a way that I can make the links target="_blank" so in-case the user does have JS disabled, it will open up in a new window?  I tried just adding that to the link, but target="_blank" overrides the JS function.  Also, absolutely phenominal point about not having href="javascript:poptastic(...), didn't even think about that!

Comment: `target="_blank"` didn't override the JS when I tried it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RevXG/5/ (applied to external and PDF links only). My click handler still worked and opened the links in a new window, but when I got rid of the JS the links opened in a new tab. Note that the user can still middle-click to open in a new tab and that _will_ bypass the JS, but then if they do a middle-click they've _chosen_ to get a new tab so I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: Oh wow! You're right! I guess it only over wrote it when i had it only doing href="javascript:poptastic(...)" but not with the new script.  Damn man, thanks so much! You have made my life SOOOOO much easier! THANK YOU :) One last thing, is there a better way to call out to my function "poptastic" without making my href="javascript:poptastic"?  I want to call one link out to my site "Privacy Policy" to open up in that window, but only if they click the link on the form.  Should i just call it out with href="javascript" or is there a better way to call it out?  Thanks again, I am so happy!

Comment: In my opinion all `<a>` tags should have a standard `href="someURL"` even if you plan to use JS to do something else, that way if JS is disabled the link still works from the user's point of view. So I'd do `<a id="privacy" href="/privacypolicy.htm">Privacy Policy</a>` (obviously putting your own appropriate url in there) and then `$("#privacy").click(...)` with the same click handler as in my answer to call your function to open a new window...

Comment: Okay, very interesting, you make a very very very valid point.  One thing I noticed when trying to switch all of my links over, the <a href="mailto:" function doesn't seem to be working even though it's being called out to at the top of the function.  [Here](http://www.remodeling-buffalo.com/alliances.php) is the page, when you scroll down to the mailto, it is set up correctly, but doesn't seem to work.  Everything else is perfect though, I honestly can't thank you enough! :)